# How can i save some data in Django without adding it in the form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model which looks like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    rate = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    userid = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.CharField() //This should be used to save the date

    def save(self): # ALL the signature

        super(MyModel, self).save()
```

And a form:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    rate = forms.CharField()
    amount = forms.FloatField()


    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ("rate", "amount")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        send = super(MyForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            send.save()
        return send
```

At the actual moment, my form is saving the fields `rate` and `amount` on my database, once the user uses the form. I would like to save on my DB the `user` who submitted the form, the date/time of when the form was saved and some other data that must not be submitted by the user, but saved 'automatically'. How can i do that in Django?

Comment: You want to save data if user does not provides value. For example, if a user doesn't input for `rate` then you save a default value for this. is it?

Comment: @shafik let me explain this better: the user inputs rate and amount, so those two fields are saved on the db. At the same time, i want to save a user and a date field on my DB, but those fields must not be submitted by the user, they should be 'pre-defined'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you refer to a user, you better use a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey):

```
from django import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class MyModel(models.Model):
    rate = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

A `ForeignKey` guarantees that it will refer to a user. Furthermore it will also lazily load the user object if you request this.

You can also set a [**`DateTimeField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField) with the [**`auto_now_add=...` parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) set to `True`. This means that it will take the value when the record has been constructed.

You can then set the user object this in the view, like:

```
from app.forms import MyForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def some_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('some_view_name')
    else:
        form = MyForm()
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'form': form})
```

Since you want to set the user for that record, you probably should decorate the view with the [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: Thank you! Would it be a good practice in Django to do the same but, instead of defining it in the model, adding an 'hidden field' with the uneditable value?

Comment: @Jack022: a hidden field is editable, even if you make it uneditable. A user can simply alter the DOM or make a POST request with a tool like cURL, postman, etc.

Comment: So it would not be safe; but if i define the field with disabled=True, would it be safe? I'm accepting in 5 minutes, thank you!

Comment: @Jack022: I think it is always better not to expose things to the user you do not need to expose, since it gives some "insights" into your database. You can make the `user` field `editable=False`, and thus it will by default not show up in your form.

Comment: One last thing: what if, the 'default' value i want my model to save, is not a date or the user id, but a variable, such as a string? Is there a way to add it to the model?

Comment: @Jack022: the same way, you can specify a default in the field with `models.CharField(max_length=128, default='some default value')`, or in the view with `form.instance.column_name = 'some other default value'`.